# Есть ли возможность как то временно отключать доп поля (TV) в модкс

Tags: modx, migx

Суть: как можно (и вообще можно ли) временно отключить нужное тв поле. Вывод идет через MIGX. Т.е хочется аналог того, как в вордпрессе работают например статус записей: "опубликовано", "на утверждении", "архив" итп. Чтобы не удалять/редактировать tvполе, а как бы временно поместить в архив.

Надеюсь понятно вопрос написал))

Comment: А как понять отключить? просто не выводите его, вы же migx как-то выводите, например через getImageList, и там в шаблоне уберите ваше тв поле, оно и не будет выводиться

Comment: Да вывожу через getImageList. У меня к примеру выводятся акции (неважно чего). Заполнил 5 позиций. Вывелось 5 акций. Пришла пора сменить 2 акции. Удалять/редактировать их не хочу, так как потом какую-то из этих акций придется опять включать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Вашем случае, не временно отключать, а фильтровать (отбирать записи) для вывода, по определенным критериям. Добавьте еще одно tv поле в ваш migx к примеру state и воспользуйтесь оператором фильтра migx, добавив в вызов сниппета:

```
&where=`{"state:=":"1"}`
```

Таким образом будут выведены только те записи, в которых tv поле state будет равно 1, остальные не будут выводиться

Более подробная информация по getImageList тут: https://webstool.ru/documentation-migx-russian.html